# How to access other installation flags in rails new --template script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While creating a new project from the Rails Application Template, how can I access other flags passed to the `rails new` command inside the template file?

```
$ rails new --api --skip-action-mailer --template path/to/template.rb
```

In my `template.rb`, I want to know that `--skip-action-mailer` was also passed to the `rails new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `template.rb` simply needs to check for the presence of `--skip-action-mailer` from `ARGV` like so:

```rb
if ARGV.include? '--skip-action-mailer'
  puts "Do something"
end
```

EDIT:
Just for future edification, all arguments passed to the `rails` command is present in `ARGV`. Running your command, ARGV would look like:

```rb
["new",
 "--api",
 "--skip-action-mailer",
 "--template",
 "path/to/template.rb",
 "ProjectName"]
```